# How do I make a hover over only take up a portion of an image as seen on gamlinwhiskeyhouse.com?

Tags: html, css

I know how to set up hover over image effects, but I cannot get mine to only show up on a portion of the image.

I am looking to set up a hover over effect as seen on this site: http://gamlinwhiskeyhouse.com/ where the overlay only takes up a portion of the image along with having another image, text, and multiple links that show up on top of the overlay. I mean, I know that they are using wordpress, but I am trying to recreate the effect in html and css.

This is what I am currently working with:

```
#myImage {
    position: relative;
    background: #0f0;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}

#innerHover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0/**distance from top of image */;
    left:0 /**distance from left of image */;
    width:100% /**region width*/;
    height:100% /**region height*/;
    overflow:show;
}
#popupdiv{
    background:#f00;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
#innerHover #popupdiv{
   display:none;
}
#innerHover:hover #popupdiv{
    display:block;
}


 <div id="myImage">
    <div id="innerHover" title="hover text"><div id="popupdiv">pop up content.</div></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DVWkT/185/

But I need the popup to have a border of 5px wide and be 90% transparent and I am not getting it to work for me.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Make the hovering element smaller than the element over which it hovers?  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: Edited the post to show what I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did they do it?

An absolutely positioned overlay with a margin for spacing. No need for an extra inner element.

```css
    #myImage {
      position: relative;
      background: #0f0;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    #popupdiv {
      background: #f00;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0/ right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: 10px;
      /* space around */
      display: none;
    }
    #myImage:hover #popupdiv {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="myImage">

  <div id="popupdiv">Fancy pop up content.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it exactly!

EDIT: Except in this case, when the text inside isn't broken up, the overlay extends out past the image to the right. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/p712oyod/

Comment: You'd get that with any method. Obviously you'd have to fit the content to the overlay...but you'd have to do that anyway...right?

Comment: BUT...you can fix long words too - https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/p712oyod/1/

Comment: I forgot about word-break. Thanks so much!